# How to find friends on Facebook by using their phone number via Facebook Graph API in C#

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, phone-number

I'm writing a tool to check a phone number that registered Facebook account or not by using C#. But I don't know which Graph API do Facebook support to C# to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple and obvious: You can't.